# OpenCV, noise when mapping a a patch of pixels from image to image

Tags: c++, opencv, mapping, pixel, copying

I am copying a patch of pixels from one image to another and as a result I am not getting a 1:1 mapping but the new image intensities differ by 1 or 2 itensity-levels from the source image.

Do you know what could be causing this?

This is the code:

```
void templateCut ( IplImage* ptr2Img, IplImage* tempCut, CvBox2D* boundingBox ) 
{ 

/* Upper left corner of target's BB */
int col1 = (int)boundingBox->center.x;
int row1 = (int)boundingBox->center.y;

for(int i=0; i<tempCut->height; i++)
        {       
        /* Pointer to a row */
            uchar * ptrImgBB = (uchar*)( ptr2Img->imageData + (row1+i)*ptr2Img->widthStep + col1 );
            uchar * ptrTemp  = (uchar*)( tempCut->imageData + i*tempCut->widthStep );

            for(int i2=0; i2<tempCut->width; i2++)
            {
                *ptrTemp++ = (*ptrImgBB++); 
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You should add a tag for the programming language you are interested at. I think this is **C** code, right?

Comment: its c++. thanks for the remark.

Comment: i thought opencv was enough to say.

Comment: It looks like you are using the older C interface. If you have OpenCV 2 installed you should be using Mat, not IplImage.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a single channel image or multiple-channel image (such as RGB)? If it is a multiple-channel image, you have to consider the channel index in your loop.

btw: OpenCV supports region of interest (ROI) which will be convenient for you to implement copying a sub-region of an image. Below is the link you can find information on ROI usage in OpenCV.

```
http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_(ROI)
```

Comment: sorry that the browser converted the brackets "()" to URL format which is not correct. I've hard coded above.

Comment: Defining regions of interest is different in the new C++ interface. You simply create a Mat object by passing a Rect to an existing Mat object: `Mat img = imread("image.jpg"); Rect r(10, 10, 100, 100); Mat smallImg = img(r);`

Comment: Yes, new version of opencv has introduced many new data structure and is more object oriented. But the code posted in the question seems to be from the old coding style.